# Passing JSON data in get request as request body

Tags: java, android, httpwebrequest, httpurlconnection

Hi i have to send a get request to an url
http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/group?authToken=access_token&authMethod=oauth

with request body contains json object as shown below.

```
{"goupid":"some_variable"
}
```

Here is a section of java code for sending get request:

```
URL url1=new URL("http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/group?authToken="+access_token+"&authMethod=oauth");
conn=(HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
JSONObject jj=new JSONObject();
HttpGet get;
get.

jj.put("groupid", "testing@iritesh.com");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-TYpe", "application/json");
conn.getOutputStream().write(jj.toString().getBytes());
conn.connect();
InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
```

I am getting an error `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

I sent a request from mozilla browser to url
http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/group?authToken=ya29.AHES6ZRDl-RqiA8W0PhybU_hMluHrHRjlJBvq06Vze0izJq0Ovjc088&authMethod=oauth
It was giving me correct response but now its more than one hour so acccesstoken expire. I know its weird to send parameter as well as requestbody in get request but i have to send it.

Please help in how to send a json object in request body in get request.

Comment: whats the random `get.` in the middle of your code?

Answer (score 14):

Don't do it.

Read this:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/9962

> "Yes. In other words, any HTTP request message is allowed to contain a
>   message body, and thus must parse messages with that in mind. Server
>   semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body, if any,
>   has no semantic meaning to the request. The requirements on parsing
>   are separate from the requirements on method semantics.
>
> So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful to
>   do so.
>
> This is part of the layered design of HTTP/1.1 that will become clear
>   again once the spec is partitioned (work in progress)."

For other interesting discussions on this check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/978094/550967

https://stackoverflow.com/a/978173/550967

https://stackoverflow.com/a/978519/550967

Answer (score 2):

The body of a GET request is not read.

Have you tried adding it to the params:

http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/group?authToken=access_token&authMethod=oauth**&goupid=some_variable**